# Single statement query

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I have this code:

```
var questionCategory = questionnaire.QuestionCategories
    .First(x => x.Type == (int)questionCategoryType);
return questionCategory.Questions.Select(x => new 
    {
       Id = x.Id,
       Text = x.Text,
    });
```

I'm interested if there is a way of shortening this into one statement, i.e. avoid making variable *questionCategory* . I'm looking for Extesion method or LINQ solution, or little bit of both :) .

Comment: use FirstOrDefault, more defensive.

Comment: Also check for null before second query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `First` forces the query to be executed (the same goes for enumerating navigation properties like `questionnaire.QuestionCategories`). This is to be avoided in order to not issue multiple queries.

```
return from qc in dataContext.QuestionCategories
       where qc.QuestionaireID == questionnaire.ID //guessing names here
       where qc.Type == (int)questionCategoryType
       from q in qc.Questions
       select new 
    {
       Id = q.Id,
       Text = q.Text,
    };
```

This will issue a single query, remoting all work to the SQL Server.

Comment: This code worked for me(I apologize for ugliness of this comment format ):            return from qc in questionnaire.QuestionCategories
                   where qc.Type == (int)questionCategoryType
                   from q in qc.Questions
                   select  new
            {
                Id = q.Id,
                Type = q.Type,
            };

Comment: This, too, will run two queries. One to fetch `questionnaire.QuestionCategories` and one for the rest. Only by putting everything into one query you can get max. efficiency. But maybe you don't need that, so it's ok.

Comment: Although the answers given by Cuong Le and Snowsickle also worked, I'm going to mark this answer as accepted because maybe it will  provide more useful information(plural :) ), for the one who visits this thread, than other two. That's my opinion, I can only mark one given answer a accepted.

Comment: @usr: I'm still skeptical on `First()`. Yes, I know First is not deferred execution. But in this case of using First, does it actually create 2 queries or just create one query and execute immediately? Anther approach which is not used First, will still be defer until the result is used.

Comment: First just executes the existing query right then. So First by itself only executes one query. The OPs code executes an additional query *after* First, making the total 2 queries.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the nicest way to do it, but you could easily simplify your code to one line with no variable storage like so:

```
return questionnaire.QuestionCategories.First(x => x.Type == (int)questionCategoryType)
                    .Questions.Select(x => new {Id = x.Id, Text = x.Text});
```

Comment: Has bad perf, though. Kind of a hack.

Comment: Because this will issue two query (one is enough), and it will download and materialize the entire questions collection. It will *not* just download Id and Text. The same goes for the other answers btw.

Comment: @usr: Then why don't you post your answer, I think that we all would like to see better solution, if not the best :)

Comment: Why this will issue two queries? my understanding is Linq will automatically translate to Sql, it implicitly one query

Comment: @kr85, you're right. I added my answer. Cuong Le, executing First returns you a QuestionCategory. This forces a query to run, or else how could the QuestionCategory be constructed?

Answer (score 1):

With this way, needless to check null on `QuestionCategories`, the final result is to `Select` on `Questions`, so you don't need to use `First`, instead, use `Where`:

```
return questionnaire.QuestionCategories 
     .Where(x => x.Type == (int)questionCategoryType) 
     .SelectMany(c => c.Questions.Select(q => new
                                        {
                                            Id = q.Id,
                                            Text = q.Text
                                        }));
```

Comment: sry, this doesn't work. "Select" method gets "QuestionCategory" instead of getting "Question".

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039) instead of [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050.aspx) so you don't get an InvalidOperationException when sequence is empty or none of the elements match your predicate.

Also you should check for null after the first query and provide a default value for that situation. This is not what you asked for but it's more defensive.

```
var questionCategory = questionnaire.QuestionCategories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == (int)questionCategoryType);

return questionCategory != null
        ? questionCategory.Questions.Select(x => new 
                                                 {
                                                    Id = x.Id,
                                                    Text = x.Text,
                                                 })
        : someDefaultValue;
```

Comment: it does not eliminate questionCategory

Comment: thanks for reply and tips. But as you said, this is not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
return questionnaire.QuestionCategories.First(x => x.Type == (int)questionCategoryType)
            .Questions.Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Text = x.Text, });
```

of if you would like to return `null` if `x.Type == (int)questionCategoryType` is not found:

```
return questionnaire.QuestionCategories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == (int)questionCategoryType)
            .Questions.Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Text = x.Text, });
```